# Как реализовать свою условную валюту на сайте?

Tags: php, paypal, webmoney, платежи

Необходимо реализовать свою валюту на сайте.

Также нужен ввод/вывод средств **MasterCard + Visa + PayPal + WebMoney** для максимального покрытия аудитории.

Примеры валют по ссылкам:

- https://egb.com/
- https://opskins.com/

Пользователь купил пакет пополнения на сайте — ему на аккаунт начислено N поинтов
(1$ = 1000 points, к примеру).

Захотел вывести — выводит на выбранный сервис; сайту и сервису % от выводимой суммы 10 000 points = 10$-%(комиссия).

Куда копать? Какие API мне использовать? Где подробно можно почитать? Алгоритм действий? Как это все сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал вам сделать в БД 2 значания(1е - сума пополнения(в доларах), 2е - сума в вашей валюте) .При пополнении баланса(на Ютубе довольно много видео уроков интеграции платежных систем на сайт) вы записываете в 1ю ячейку саму суму пополнения а во 2ю эту суму умноженую на ваш коофициент. Вывод же делать почти что в обратном порядке(ну понятно, проверки там всякие), вычитаете процент который остаеться на сайте, а на кошелёк выводите заданую пользователем суму делённую на кооф и отнимаете от неё процент.

P.S Чисто мой взгляд на ситуацию,и ещё проще перечислять со своего кошелька, чём подключать платёжные системы. Вот вам сервис можете через него сделать http://payin-payout.net